# Arduino to Processing: Lever switch not constantly printing serial value

Tags: processing, processing.js

I have the below Processing code that reads in serial values from Arduino button switch. When a lever button is pressed and have a certain potentiometer values, it prints "recording scene n". The text here is static, but when I tried to now put in other animation/draw features into Processing, Processing only goes 1 loop of draw() only when the lever switch is clicked, while I want the loop to be going on constantly. I'm not sure why it is keep doing it.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
//String val; 
int val; 
int end = 10;

void setup() {
  // initial setup
  size(400,400);

  //println(Serial.list());
  String portName = Serial.list()[1]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);

}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available() > 0) { 
  //val = myPort.readStringUntil(end);
  //val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  val = myPort.read();
  println(val);

  if (val == 11) {
      println(val);
      background(127,0,0); //color red
      textSize(32);
      text("RECORDING SCENE 1", 50, 200); 
      fill(255, 255, 255);
  }
  if (val == 22) {
    background(127,0,0); //color red
    textSize(32);
    text("RECORDING SCENE 2", 50, 200); 
    fill(255, 255, 255);
  }
  if (val == 33) {
    background(127,0,0); //color red
    textSize(32);
    text("RECORDING SCENE 3", 50, 200); 
    fill(255, 255, 255);
  }
  if (val == 44) {
    background(127,0,0); //color red
    textSize(32);
    text("RECORDING SCENE 4", 50, 200); 
    fill(255, 255, 255);
  }
  if (val == 55) {
    background(127,0,0); //color red
    textSize(32);
    text("RECORDING SCENE 5", 50, 200); 
    fill(255, 255, 255);
  }
  //else {
  if (val == 66) {  
    background(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
}
```

Any help or guides would be appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: The `draw()` function is called 60 times per second. You have an `if` statement that only draws stuff if  `myPort.available() > 0`, and then more `if` statements that check the `val`. Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out which of those `if` statements is evaluating to false?

Comment: @KevinWorkman hey thanks for the reply. Yes, so there are total 6 conditions, and whenever any of single condition is met, it is supposed to keep drawing, while the rest of the 5 if statements are false. Theoretically thinking, isn't it supposed to work like: if the first condition is met, implement first condition and loop.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Try adding a `println()` statement as the first line in `draw()` to see that the function is being called 60 times per second.

Comment: Yeah, so what it does is, it only prints 11 or 66 whenever the button is pressed or released. Then when I release it, it prints 66. But, nothing happens whenever I have the switch either pressed or released.

Comment: My guess is that the `draw()` function is still firing, but the first `if` statement in your `draw()` function is evaluating to false, so it's skipping all of your drawing code.

Comment: @Vinci just reading the code, it looks like it should work as you expect. The only thing I'm not 100% sure of is how you send the values from Arduino (for example if you send a byte that might be read as a -127 to 127 value in Processing Java instead of 0-255 as you're expecting, a terminator character (NL/CR) not trimmed, etc.). If you can post your Arduino code and a snippet of the output from Serial Monitor, that will also help

Comment: hey, thanks for the guide. I realized it was problem with my Arduino :(. Stupid mistake! Thanks!!

Comment: @Vinci well done on spotting the error. I recommend posting the solution to your problem as an answer. This way, others may learn from your experience.